# installation of SQL Server 2005 Express edition in Windows 7

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

I recently installed VS 2008 express edition on windows 7(32 bit system). Then installed SQL Server 2005 SP3 Express edition.

But the problem is I am not able to create a database in my SQL Server (I am not able to find  the option to create a database, though i have added given admin role)

Can someone pls help me out with this.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CLI Tool sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress -E

Create Database test;
Go
exot
```

or you can download and install SSMSE.